# Add nine patch as background of a shape XML

Tags: android, xml

I have this drawable to set as a background of a Layout (i call the nine patch after the shape so you can see what it draws):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#F000" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1px"
            android:color="#BB000000" />

        <padding
            android:bottom="7dp"
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:top="7dp" />

        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topRightRadius="0dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="270"
            android:startColor="#FFDF00"
            android:centerColor="#FFD700"
            android:endColor="#D4AF37"
            android:type="linear" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/outerglow" />
</item>
```

[image]

As you can see the nine patch doesn't take the size that I wanted to. I think it needs to add some padding, the same as the `shape`, but a `bitmap` doesn't receive the property `<padding>`. I'm afraid I can't add the `<gradient>` to the nine patch because then I won't be able to add `<corners>`.

I wanted to organize this by XML, so avoid giving solutions to do this by Java.
Thanks!

Comment: You probably stretched your 9Patch wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably better off making the whole drawable a 9-patch. I'm not sure you can mix and match this way.

Comment: Yes you're right, and I can draw this drawable in a 9-patch. I just didn't see by the right way (tiredness...)